# How to amend my php function to add extra text?

Tags: php

Note that I used this with wordpress.

I added this function to functions.php:

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
    { 
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words);
}
```

I added this to my html:

```
<?php if ( $woo_options['woo_post_content_home'] == "true" ) the_content(); else $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,38); ?>
```

What this does is shortens the text to the number of words specified (in this sample its 38). What I want to do is add [...] after those 38 words. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh...

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
    { 
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words) . '...';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
    { 
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  {
      array_pop($words);
      $words[] = '[...]';
  }
  return implode(' ', $words);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
echo string_limit_words($excerpt,38) . " ...";
```

should suffice.

Comment: this adds the ... even if  there is less than 38 words originally

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the function like this so it will add the ellipses only when shorten the phrase.

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
    { 
  $ellipses = '';
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit) {
    array_pop($words);
    $ellipses = ' ...';
  }
  $newString = implode(' ', $words) + $ellipses;
  return $newString
}
```